# Database.ExecuteSqlCommand what means int return?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an sql query that delete some files at table

I'm running it using EF

```
string comando = $" delete from MyTable where IdProduccion = '{idProduccion}'";
int res = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comando);
if (res < 0)
   throw new Exception("....")
```

Some times it returns 0 another times returns 1 or another int, searching trough documentation I have this

```
Return Value
Type: System.Int32
The result returned by the database after executing the command.
```

But What exactly means that integer ?

If I have a result other than 0, an error happens at Db?

Answer (score 2):

```
int res = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(comando);
```

The `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns the total number of rows affected by `DELETE` action. For example, as your delete action result if `2` rows are deleted, it should return as `2`.

> If I have a result other than 0, an error happens at Db?

No, don't use the return value for checking the some kind of errors. If an error occurs in SQL Server, It throws an error and It could be better to use `try/catch` block to handle errors.